# Relation between products and sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_{j}\}$ is a sequence taking values in $(0,1)$.How do I show that $$\prod^{\infty}_{j=1} (1-a_{j}) > 0  \iff \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{j} < \infty$$

I should probably apply the logarithm to the left and compare the resulting series with the right, but I'm not sure what properties of the logarithm to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1-a_{k}}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_{k}+a_{k}^{2}+...)\leq\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_{k})\leq1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$$
 So, if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}=c<\infty$, then $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-a_{k})>1/(c+1)$

In other hand, $$\prod_{k=0}^{n}(1-a_{k})\leq(\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}(1-a_{k})}{n})^{^{n}}=(1-\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}}{n})^{n}
 $$  by AG inequality. So, if $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}>c$, then $\prod_{k=0}^{n}(1-a_{k})<exp(-c)$ and if $\sum a_{k}
 $ is unbounded, $\prod_{k=0}^{n}(1-a_{k})\rightarrow0$